# 10.18.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] AppCheck failed:

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check

Using flutter to build an IOS app. I have enabled IOS App Attest on Firebase and have made this call

```
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
          options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
      // For web
      //webProvider: ReCaptchaV3Provider('recaptcha-v3-site-key'),
      // Default provider for Android (choose based on your need)
      androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug, // Adjust as needed
      // Default provider for iOS/macOS (choose based on your need)
      appleProvider: AppleProvider.appAttest, // Adjust as needed
    );
```

It seem's like nothing I am doing is actually helping. I keep receiving unverified requests when checking the App Check API calls. 100% of the calls are unverified. I am using a physical IOS device, I have made sure I am using the correct bundle ID in GoogleService.plist file and have successfully registered that id on App Check, I have made sure I have the App Attest Certification on the Bundle ID in the apple developer portal and adding the signing certification App Attest to the capabilities. I am stuck and need help. This is the error that I am getting -

`10.18.0 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] AppCheck failed: 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.app_check_core error 0.)'`

Sometimes I get this error as well -

`10.18.0 - [FirebaseAuth][I-AUT000018] Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: Error Domain=com.google.app_check_core Code=1 "API request error." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=API request error., NSUnderlyingError=0x280953810 {Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."`

**EDIT**
I am using a custom JWT token to authenticate my users. This is the only way user's can sign into the app currently. Could this be a potential reason why App Check is failing?

Comment: Is your AppAttest environment set to production?

Comment: No, it's still in development. I will try to set it to production within the certification Apple automatically produced when adding the capability in Xcode.

Comment: I updated the AppAttest environment to be production and I am still getting an error - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] AppCheck failed: 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.app_check_core error 0.)'

Comment: In PROD I'm facing a similar issue with FirebaseAppCheck (10.18.0)
FirebaseAppCheck (10.15.0) works perfect though...